Story about immortality sustained by machines, leading to no one being able to have children and injuries not healing
Does anyone remember a story about a guy travelling the world after everyone has been made 'immortal'? Immortality is maintained by a network of machines around the world.
Because of the way the machines work, no one can have any children. 
I think there was also a complication: injuries don't heal as a result. If I remember correctly, the story starts just after his dog has been killed/hurt in an accident, and he can't heal it.
It turns out that the guy is the person who installed the machines, but he doesn't remember for some reason. I think it was a short story written by one of the golden age authors.
I think I probably read it in the 80s.

@user14111 My bad, I didn't intend to. I blame my grammar correction software. ☺

"The End of Summer", a novelette by Algis Budrys which was also the answer to the old question "Memory suitcase" story; first published in Astounding Science Fiction, November 1954, available at the Internet Archive. You may have read it in one of these compilations.
ISFDB synopsis:

A man develops immortality for humans and other animals at the cost of anterograde amnesia, which is overcome by people recording their memories every day and replaying them again the next day.

He accidentally runs over a dog, but it's not his:

He tried to snap the car out of the way, his face suddenly white, but the dog moved unpredictably, its abrupt yell of pain louder than the scream of Fay's brakes. He felt the soft bump, and then his foot jerked away from the clutch and the car stalled convulsively. Even with his engine dead and the car still, he heard no further sound from the dog.
Then he saw the Homebody boy running toward him up the road, and the expression of his face changed from shocked unpleasantness to remorseful regret. He sighed and climbed out of the car clumsily, trying to think of something to say.

The guy who ran over the dog is responsible for creating the network of satellites that blanket the Earth in some kind of radiation that makes everybody immortal but has bad side effects such as amnesia.

That's the one, thank you for a very helpful answer.

You're welcome!
